# How to decide width and height for SVG sprite in AndEngine

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am using AndEngine to load a svg images as my Sprites.

The problem I am having with this is that i can't figure out how to scale the image to fit the particular device on which it is being run.

```
sprite= new Sprite(positionX, positionY, WIDTH,HEIGHT,TextureRegion);
```

The parameters that it takes are the position's on x and y coordinates, and then width, and height.

The problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to scale the sprite to the right width and height for how I want it.

For example I have a title, and I want the title to be bigger on bigger devices, how would I decide if the device is bigger and scale it up for a bigger screen and down for a smaller screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a constant camera size, *all* of the screen is scaled (Hence all of the entities).

Decide on a constant size, for exaple `720x480`.

```
final static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
final static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
```

Then, when creating the engine options, use:

```
... new EngineOptions(... new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), ...);
```

On each device, the camera will scale itself to fit the resolution as good possible, while *keeping* the ratio between width & height.
Now, when creating a sprite, just do:

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(x, y, TextureRegion);
```

*Don't* give the sprite size! Its size comparing to the camera size will be decided according to the texture region size, and *it will be a constant one.* **Then**, it will be scaled by the camera-to-device-screen scaling, which changes from one device to another, but the ratio will remain constant - the game will not look like a bad scaled image on devices with a different resoltuion that the camera width/height ratio.

I think that's a great method that AndEngine provides to deal with different screen resolution; IMHO, it is the best to use.